# Rename nested field name while creating nested pyspark data frime

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
POA_KEY addressIdentifier,
PROV_SPCLTY_CERTFN_STTS_CD spcltyBoardCertificationCode,
PROV_SPCLTY_CERTFN_STTS_CD txnmyBoardCertificationCode,
SPCLTY_CD_VAL specialtyCode,
SPCLTY_CD_VAL_NM specialtyCodeName,
SPCLTY_CD_VAL_DESC specialtyCodeDesc,
SPCLTY_CTGRY_CD_VAL specialtyCategoryCode,
SPCLTY_CTGRY_CD_VAL_NM specialtyCategoryName,
SPCLTY_CTGRY_CD_VAL_DESC specialtyCategoryDesc,
TXNMY_CD_VAL taxonomyCode,
TXNMY_CD_VAL_NM taxonomyCodeName,
TXNMY_CD_VAL_DESC taxonomyCodeDesc
FROM TEST A
```

I am creating a df from above query. and making a nested df using agg.

```
contact_df_gp= exprt_df.groupby('addressIdentifier').agg(
  
    f.collect_list(
      f.struct('contactListCode','contactListDesc','contactListNm','phoneNumber')
    
  ).alias('contactLis'),
    f.collect_list(
      f.struct('displayUrl','urlName')
  ).alias('webContactList')
)
```

I need to rename  contactListCode -> Code ,contactListDesc->Desc and contactListNm -> Name

Expected out put.

```
{"addressIdentifier":1000105107,"contact":[{"Code":"B","Desc":"BUSINESS","Name":"BUSINESS","phoneNumber":"8037735227"},{"Code":"B","Desc":"BUSINESS","Name":"BUSINESS","phoneNumber":"8037735227"}],"contactweb":[{"displayUrl":"FALSE"},{"displayUrl":"FALSE"}]}
{"addressIdentifier":1000000001,"contact":[{"Code":"B","Desc":"BUSINESS","Name":"BUSINESS","phoneNumber":"7045403667"},{"Code":"B","Desc":"BUSINESS","Name":"BUSINESS","phoneNumber":"7045403667"},{"contactListCode":"B","contactListDesc":"BUSINESS","contactListNm":"BUSINESS","phoneNumber":"7045403667"},{"contactListCode":"B","contactListDesc":"BUSINESS","contactListNm":"BUSINESS","phoneNumber":"7045403667"}],"contactweb":[{"displayUrl":"FALSE"},{"displayUrl":"FALSE"},{"displayUrl":"FALSE"},{"displayUrl":"FALSE"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contact_df_gp= exprt_df.groupby('addressIdentifier').agg(
    f.collect_list(
      f.struct(
        f.col('contactListCode').alias('Code'),
        f.col('contactListDesc').alias('Desc'),
        f.col('contactListNm').alias('Name'),
        f.col('phoneNumber')
     )
    ).alias('contactLis'),
    f.collect_list(
      f.struct('displayUrl','urlName')
    ).alias('webContactList')
)
```